# Laravel collection return Array

Tags: php, laravel, collections

So i have this table

```
|id|    price    |  start_time |
--------------------------------
|1 |    45000.00 |  04:45:00   |
|1 |    45000.00 |  07:00:00   |
|2 |    40000.00 |  01:20:00   |
```

I want to make a collection that return json like this

```json
{
   id: 1
   price: 45000.00
   start_time: [
        04:45:00, 07:00:00
    ]
},
{
   id: 2
   price: 40000.00
   start_time: [
        01:20:00
    ]
}
```

I spent a lot of time to figure it out but I can't do it

Please help me to figure it out,thanks in advance

Comment: u want in in hole application or in single route .?

Comment: in a single route

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `map()`

```php
 $laravelCollcetion->map(function($row){
       return $row['start_time'] = [$row['start_time']]
  })

return $laravelCollcetion;
```

ref link https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#extending-collections

---

for your db instance u can do like this

```php
 $data = \DB::table('schedules')
        ->select(\DB::raw('id, price,GROUP_CONCAT(start_time) as start_time'))
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->get();

return $data;
```

Comment: and now iam struggling at my queries , my queries right now is DB::table('schedules')->select('id','price','start')->groupBy('id', 'price')->get(); but i turns out an error . do you have any idea what queies  should i use. thanks in advance